# Angular 9.1.x, hundreds of routes work well, less one

Tags: angular, laravel, routes

**UPDATE:** The problem was not with the API, but with Angular. See answer below.

I have had an App working for years, and I have never had problems with routes.
This past weekend, after deploying some updates, I discovered that one of the routes is not called at all.

I lost the weekend trying to debug, but I can't find anything. The route is simply not called. No requests are received by Laravel.

It is the inclusion of records, exactly like the other dozens of inclusions that already exist. Nothing different.

I changed the order of the routes. I changed from put to post and vice versa. I changed the name of the class. I changed name of Controller. I made changes to the client (Angular 9). None of this worked and the server and client do not display any type of error. It just doesn't work.

In the same controller all other routes work normally for delete, update, export, print, etc ...

I also created middleware to see all requests that arrive at the server and nothing appears ...

Any suggestion?

All my routes have this structure ...

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth:api'],
    'prefix' => 'prefix-route'
], function () {
    Route::post('route-name', 'ControllerName@addRegister');
});
```

And my controllers are like this ... (I did not put Trait because it is not the case)

```
public function addRegister(Request $request)
    {
       $response = $this->methodName($request['data']);
       return response()->json($response, $this->sucessStatus);
    }
```

I changed the names just to simplify the understanding.

I appreciate any help or tip !!

And of course, everything works perfectly in the dev environment!

Comment: so what is happening since it isn't called at all?

Comment: Nothing. no error, no messages.

Comment: Not even a HTTP Error, but a simple 200 OK? Is there any content in the response?

Comment: No. No 200 response! nothing... it's a big mystery!!

Comment: There are no mysteries lol. Have you tried calling that route from an API testing tool like Postman? Change that route to return something from a closure function just for testing?

Comment: @user3532758 no, I'll try. Very complex to simulate in Postman, but I'll try.
Now, I changed this route to a new service in Angular, but nothing...

Comment: @user3532758, "Change that route to return something from a closure function just for testing? " it's a good idea. I'll try this too

Comment: @user3532758, I tried clousure function, but nothing! Work fine in dev, nothing in production...

Comment: if it's working fine in dev, then it must be a configuration issue in production. Be bold, enable debugging if you haven't already. :)

Comment: @user3532758, sorry, honestly i didn't try to see with debug enabled because as no error was happening ... but i will try now! thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @user3532758, how crazy! debug also does not appear!
4 years working with Laravel / Angular, I have never seen anything like it!

Comment: @user3532758, again, thank for a help!
I did the tests with Postman and it worked!
At least now we know that the problem (probably) is with Angular. I will investigate what it may be and if I find any answer, I post it here to let everyone know!
Thanks for the Postman tip. It is known that laziness does not take anyone anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I also went in for the issue what I did:-

1. php artisan route:clear
2. Check for duplicate routes
3. next($request) missing in some middleware.

Comment: I didn't mention above, but I also tried this and nothing ...Thanks! and not duplicates...

Comment: I have duplicate route, but with different type (put and post), but when I change name, the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the error was because I forgot to pass the parameters to POST as a string, one of them was being sent as an object, without the proper JSON.stringify ().

What I can't understand is why Angular didn't "complain" about anything. No message? No warning?

I did not receive error messages (live or compiled), everything worked fine in dev, but not in prod.